# How to avoid accidental invocation on UIKit's private classes?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, private-methods

I have just encountered very weird problem. In my current project i am working with complex views and doing some modifications on the fly.

e.g. If view responds to setTextColor then was setting new color by using following code

```
if ([view respondsToSelector:propertySelector]) {
    // Invoke method.
}
```

Accidentally calling method returned `UIButtonLabel` (which is private hidden
class in `UIKit`), and executed above method. In above code `UIButtonLabel` responded to
`setTextColor:` but then application crashed in the invocation.

How to avoid accidental access and invocation on `UIKit`'s private classes ?

Comment: ??? Just make sure that the method you are calling is declared in the header.  Also don't just tromp through the subviews of a UIKit provided view as you please.

Comment: @borrrden any programatic way to check and avoid this situation?

Comment: Not with the way you are doing it.  You should check if the view is a certain type of class, not if it responds to a selector.  There is no such thing as private methods (in the traditional sense) in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can traverse reverse superclasses chain starting from `NSObject` up to your class, checking that your method is not part of `class_copyMethodList` for the currently inspected class and it's metaclass (for class methods). While doing so, check that the currently inspected class is not coming from your `[NSBundle mainBundle]` (`[NSBundle bundleForClass:]`) as soon as it does, you can terminate the search - you reached your code. But, as you can imagine, even with caching it's a *really* slow way of doing things.

You are probably better of by redesigning your code: try using `conformsToProtocol:` instead of `respondsToSelector`. For example you declare a protocol

```
@protocol XYZSettableColor <NSObject>

@required
- (void)setSomethingWithColor:(UIColor *)textColor;

@end
```

Then, in you class (classes) you want to declare that it conforms to the protocol (and obviously implement required methods)

```
@interface XYZMyControl : UIControl <XYZSettableColor>

@end
```

Then later, when you want to make sure that passed component is qualified to execute specified method:

```
- (void)applyTextColor:(UIColor *)color toControl:(id)control {
    if ([control conformsToProtocol:@protocol(XYZSettableColor)]) {
        [(id<XYZSettableColor>)control setSomethingWithColor:color];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you point me to some example which demonstrates conformsToProtocol usage?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no way 100% sure to check this.
You've got to know that objective-c works with method invocations, which means there is no real private method. (At least, anyone can invoke "private" methods).

To prevent calling such methods, you should avoid using "performSelector" and other invocation methods with selectors that you don't already know about.

Moreover, a safeguard exists during the app-submition process. At the end of the submition process, if you have used "risky" selectors, or method calls with names that Apple knows as "method used in private API", then a warning will appear, telling you where you have used private API.

So in the end, everything should be fine at the end of the submission process.